# How should I handle posts incorrectly voted for closure?

Tags: discussion

What is the recommended way to handle closed posts or close votes for an incorrect reason? For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61249878/584676) asks about how to disable functionality in a programming tool. Some have voted to close as unfit for Stack Overflow, even though questions about development tools [are allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). To quote (emphasis added by me):

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel [the best Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

I caught this in the review queue, and thought it was a test at first - I was surprised when it wasn't, so I actually went in and answered the question, and leaving a comment reminder that this sort of question is considered on-topic. Is this the most I should do in this case? Or should I flag for moderator intervention?

My concern is that, while in this case I knew the answer and was able to provide a complete answer for the asker, but what if OP didn't get their answer, and it was marked to be closed? Now OP doesn't get an answer for their question until *maybe* it gets enough reopen votes, or they go ask in another community that may be less suited for development tools in favor of general computing knowledge instead.

As I understand the guidelines I posted earlier - questions having to do with the development tool itself should be on-topic for Stack Overflow, but specific questions about implementation may not be on topic. For example, having trouble with the Vagrant DSL syntax or a configuration setting of the program would be on topic here, but the questions about network configuration of a VM *using* Vagrant might be better suited for ServerFault.

Comment: You leave a comment and follow it. If it's closed, vote to reopen. Not everyone is aware of where exactly the line goes, so a comment alone could prevent that third vote. Mods can't do anything here. There have been cases of invalid close votes here on meta, where they're cleared by closing the question, and reopening it. There's not much else to do

Comment: I feel it's a bit of a weakness with the system that you can't "vote against" a closevote, but does the new "follow" feature give a notification for closure at least?`

Comment: You are able to "vote against" a close vote by using the `Leave Open` button, but AFAIK this does not count against the close votes already on the question. IMO this would be a welcome improvement to the current review process.

Comment: "Leave open" in close vote review still leaves the votes there. If review is left with a result of "Leave open" but has 2 close votes, those votes are _not_ invalidated. A third vote can still come in after review and close the question.

Comment: So by that logic, ten people could say "hey this question is okay", and click `Leave Open`, but three others could vote to close and their opinion is weighed more than the other votes? I don't think that's the correct way to go about it. If you can vote against, you should be able to have a proper vote "in favor of", and have it be weighed appropriately. Although this is less of what I'm asking about and more wishful thinking about moderation votes.

Comment: @ivarni it apparently does not. It does send notifications for dupe closure comments, but not the actual closure itself.

Comment: I mean... have you considered that maybe you're wrong, and it actually is off topic?

Comment: @KevinB FWIW, if we're considering the question linked here as off-topic, and that turns into community consensus, we're gonna have to clean up [tag:vim] and move stuff to vi.SE. There's many Vim config questions out there, and the same goes with other editors and IDEs and various settings. In its current form, it isn't off-topic.

Comment: Yeah, no, the question in question is on topic. I find that to be rare. the exception to normal.

Comment: @kevinb According to the rules I've quoted above, it's not. The question is literally about disabling **code completion** in a text editor. I can't find any way to find that question off topic on a programming Q&A site.

Comment: FWIW I don't see any pending close votes on it now

Comment: In the time since I've asked this, the question received that third close vote, I voted to reopen and it looks like two others have as well.

Comment: Ah ok.. I should have checked the timeline.

Comment: Could be the third close vote was to clear the close votes. /shrug

Comment: @KevinB I agree most times when something is closed, IME it's closed for the right reason. However, I see close votes often on questions which ask on trouble with dev tools and not programming specifically. So I was curious if there is anything specific I can do to help these questions. But it seems what I've done is about the best we can do as a community.

Comment: The 3 votes to close prevent usually that ones own discomfort, is ground for closure. without knowing the re4asons for the first closure vote ground, also you should remember everyone has ihis own standards. I alo would vote to keep it open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this the most I should do in this case?

Pretty much. You could up-vote it too, if you think it deserves up-voting.

> Or should I flag for moderator intervention?

It's moderators' job to do things we can't do ourselves. If you can do an action yourself (like close a question, or re-open it) then you should probably not ask a Moderator to do it. It isn't a good use of their time.

> My concern is that, while in this case I knew the answer and was able to provide a complete answer for the asker, but what if OP didn't get their answer, and it was marked to be closed? Now OP doesn't get an answer for their question until maybe it gets enough reopen votes, or they go ask in another community that may be less suited for development tools in favor of general computing knowledge instead.

I understand your concern because I've shared them at one time or another.

At the end of the day, this is why we have re-open votes. If you think a question is incorrectly closed, you can cast a re-open vote. If you think that it won't get enough re-open votes because it's not a highly active question, or something, you have a couple of options.

The first is to bring it up here on Meta and argue why you think it should be open. This will usually bring it to the attention of more than enough people to re-open the question,. If you've argued the case well enough, you are likely to get the votes you need to re-open.

The second is to bring it up in a moderation chat room like [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). SOCVR allows people to ask for questions to be re-opened. Just make sure you follow [their rules](https://socvr.org/faq#what-are-the-chat-room-rules) when you ask (also [some other good things to know about their rules](https://socvr.org/faq#general-expectations-for-members)).

You should know that I advise against asking on Meta and *then* SOCVR. They (SOCVR) don't like getting involved in questions where Meta is already involved.

Comment: I did not know about SOCVR, I appreciate the links to the room and rules.

Comment: Well, you could also start a Twitter campaign. It has been effective in the past.